# Crystal Report 10.5 [included with Visual Studio 2008] Selection by Image column

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have an Image column (Allow Null = true) in SQL Server 2005. I am using Crystal Reports designer (ver 10.5) that comes with Visual Studio 2008. Crystal sees the column as blob field and puts an image object for the column.
  When I am trying to limit the record selection by using

```
 NOT ISNULL({Employee.Picture})
```

as Selection Formula, I get the following error:

> Error in formula  .
>   'NOT (ISNULL({Employee.Picture}))'
>   This function cannot be used because it must be evaluated later.

Is there a way to filter out rows with out pictures?

Thanks,
Kishore A

Answer (score 1):

The `ISNULL` function is more like the `SWITCH` function in in VB.  What you are looking for is probably something more along the lines of:

```
WHERE NOT Employee.Picture IS NULL
```

Two separate words for `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

since no one is jumping in on this I'll try (note: i can't test these possibilities at the moment).

- if you can get a size out of the
  field using the formula editor, try
  size greater than 0 or whatever.
- if you pull the field on the report,
      does it show a pic?
- if you look at the database, are the
      empty field actually null or could
      CR be reading them as "0"?